# How can you upgrade Nookling Junction into T&T Mart in Animal Crossing: New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

How can you upgrade Nookling Junction into T&T Mart in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*? I don't know how to upgrade Nookling Junction.

Comment: You are here ..at night....

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170529/how-do-you-upgrade-nook-n-go-into-nookway-in-animal-crossing-city-folk

Comment: @Memor-X no its not a duplicate

Comment: @Memor-X That's City Folk; to my knowledge, they're two different games.

Comment: Yeah, they are two different games.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Animal Crossing](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/T&T_Mart) wiki:

> To upgrade to T&T Mart, the player must have spent 10,000 Bells towards their House Mortgage and 12,000 Bells on items at Nookling Junction. The player must also wait for 10 days after the Town's creation before the option to upgrade is made available.

So spend lots of money in the store, and start paying off your mortgage.  That will upgrade the store.

Answer (score 1):

According to [animal crossing new leaf wikispaces](http://acwiki3ds.wikispaces.com/Nookling+Stores)

> Ten days after your Town's creation, and after spending 12,000 bells or buying 15 items, and after upgrading your tent to a house, Timmy and Tommy will find it profitable to upgrade their shop to T&T Mart. This improved store is open for more hours and has space for one extra furniture piece, fortune cookie, and tool. It also adds brand new items such as medicine, a set of wallpaper, flooring, and a feature called the Catalog. The 'Catalog' allows you to order by mail any saleable item you have had in your pocket or purse (in your inventory).
>
> This upgraded establishment finally looks like a real store, with a brand new convenience store look. It features an electric sliding door and large glass windows across the front of the store. The store's name and logo are now lit up on electric signs atop the building which stand out more during the nightly hours.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first, pay off your first home loan. Then, you have to  spend at least 12,000 bells at nookling junction to upgrade the shop. Hope it it helps!

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to T&T Mart, you have to spend 12,000 bells in the shop and have a house, rather than a tent, but only items that can be "sold out" apply. Fortune cookies count as 500 bells. (pay your down payment of 10,000 bells to Tom Nook)
Then, time travel 10 days in the future so Nookling Junction is closed for the day. Just change the date to the next day, and T&T Mart will be there.

Answer (score -1):

You have spend 10,000 bells towards your mortgage and 12,000 bells on stuff at nookling junction. You also have to wait 10 days since the town has been created before it upgrades.

Answer (score -1):

> For Nookling Junction to upgrade into T&T Mart, the following prerequisites must first be met:
>
> - 10,000 Bell home deposit paid to Tom Nook
> - 12,000 Bells spent at Nookling Junction
> - 10 days have passed since town creation

[image]
[Source](http://nookipedia.com/wiki/Nookling_Junction#Upgrading)

Answer (score -1):

10 days after town is built

10 thousand bells spent at nookling junction

12 thousand bells at nooks homes

And then nookling junction will be closed for one day 
Then t&t mart will be there

Answer (score -1):

Also: You can accomplish this almost immediately if you just keep buying a whole lot of paper, since paper does not sell out!

Answer (score -1):

You need to have spent 10,000 bells on your Home Mortgage, buy 15 items at Nooking Junction or spend 12,000 bells at Nooking Junction,and wait till it has been 10 days sense the town has been built.

Soon, Nooking Junction will be closed for 1 day and the next day T&T Mart will be there.

Comment: You can also get lots of **bold** Paper or **bold** Wrapping Paper.

Comment: Oops! i meant to do **Paper** or **Wrapping Paper**!